# How do I Populate Multiple collapsible Material-UI Nested Lists from an Array and Have Separate State

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, nested-lists, react-state-management

I want my SideMenu to have multiple list items that can open and collapse *separately*, displaying nested items. I end up getting list items that expand and collapse *simultaneously*.

Tried this:

```
const authNavigation = [
    {
      name: 'Organization Management', icon: <OrgIcon/>,
      subMenu: [
        { name: 'Accounts', to: './organization/accounts' },
        { name: 'Organization Details', to: './organization/details' },
      ]
    },
    {
      name: 'Tasks', icon: <TasksIcon/>,
      subMenu: [
        { name: 'Home', to: './tasks' },
        { name: 'New Task', to: './Tasks/create' },
        { name: 'Requests', to: './tasks/requests' },
        { name: 'Feedback', to: './tasks/feedback' }
      ]
    },
    { name: 'Recruiting', to: './recruiting', icon: <RecruitingIcon /> },
    { name: 'Announcements', to: './announcementrs', icon: <AnnouncementsIcon/> },
    checkAccess({ allowedRoles: [ROLES.ADMIN] }) && {
      name: 'Users',
      to: './users',
      icon: UsersIcon,
    },
  ].filter(Boolean) as SideNavigationItem[];

const DrawerInner = () => {
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);

    const handleClick = () => {
      setOpen(!open)
    };

    return (
       <div>
        <List>
          {authNavigation.map((item, index) => {
            // if there is a submenu for this navigation item, display a nested menu
            if (item.subMenu) {
              return (
                <div key={item.name}>
                  <ListItemButton onClick={handleClick}>
                    <ListItemIcon>
                      {item.icon}
                    </ListItemIcon>
                    <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
                    {open ? <ExpandLess /> : <ExpandMore />}
                  </ListItemButton><Collapse in={open} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                    <List component="div" disablePadding>
                      {item.subMenu.map((item, index) => (
                        <NavLink to={item.to} key={item.name}>
                          <ListItemButton sx={{ pl: 4 }}>
                            <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
                          </ListItemButton>
                        </NavLink>
                      ))}
                    </List>
                  </Collapse>
                </div>
              )
            // list items without a submenu
            } else {
              return (
                <div key={item.name}>
                  <NavLink to={item.to}>
                    <ListItem disablePadding>
                      <ListItemButton>
                        <ListItemIcon>
                          {item.icon}
                        </ListItemIcon>
                        <ListItemText primary={item.name} />
                      </ListItemButton>
                    </ListItem>
                  </NavLink>
                </div>
              )
            }
          }
          )}
        </List>
      </div >
    )
  };
```

And get this: [result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Kz8X.png) Both drop downs open simultaneously because they share the same `open` state variable.

How can I manage state between these list items so they open/close separately, given that the list is populated from the `authNavigation` array? (Typescript please)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to establish an initial state for each of your routes. Since each route needs to track it's own boolean flag, you could use the `name` property as a key in this new initial state object.

To create this initial state from your existing array of information, use the `.map()` method to form a new array of arrays of `key-value pairs`. Once you have these pairs defined, you can then use `Object.fromEntries()` method to form a new object of false boolean values for each key name.

For example, once you have defined `authNavigation`, below you would write:

```
const initialState = Object.fromEntries(authNavigation.map((i) => ([i.name, false])));
```

The resulting object looks like:

```
{
  'Organization Management': false,
  'Tasks': false,
  'Recruiting': false,
  'Announcements': false
}
```

Now you feed this initial state into your current state:

`const [open, setOpen] = useState(initialState);`

Your `handleClick` function will need to be updated as well to know "what" tab needs to be toggled:

```
const handleClick = (itemName: string) => {
  setOpen((o) => ({ ...initialState, [itemName]: !o[itemName] }));
};
```

What's happening above is the `handleClick` function now takes an input parameter which is the `key` of the new `initialState` object. We first need to bring in the existing state value using `setOpen((o) ...` where `o` is the non-stale version of `open`. So this essentially sets the initial state again, then sets the tab we're interacting with to be the opposite of what it currently is.

Finally down below where you pass the handler, you need to use:

`<ListItemButton onClick={() => handleClick(item.name)}>`

Here's an [example sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react18-2-typescript-derived-nested-state-1mh49t) of your code (stripped down a bit) that demonstrates this functionality.